# Want to add custom block at 0 index in Basic category - Grapesjs

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I have added a custom block in the basic category with this function

> editor.BlockManager.add(id, {})

It adds at the last position.

Is there any way to add this block at the first position?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same requirement, I have done it adding a negative `order` property like below:

```
editor.BlockManager.add('my-id',{
    ///...
    category: {
        label:'My Cat Label',
        order: -1, //===>Adjust accordingly
        open: true
    },
    //....
});
```